# can I add to a private list directly through the getter?

Tags: java

I realize I'm going to get flamed for not simply writing a test myself... but I'm curious about people's opinions, not just the functionality, so... here goes...

I have a class that has a private list.  I want to add to that private list through the public getMyList() method.

so... will this work?

```
public class ObA{
 private List<String> foo;
public List<String> getFoo(){return foo;}
}

public class ObB{
   public void dealWithObAFoo(ObA obA){
     obA.getFoo().add("hello");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that will absolutely work - which is usually a bad thing. (This is because you're really returning a *reference* to the collection object, not a copy of the collection itself.)

Very often you want to provide genuinely read-only access to a collection, which usually means returning a read-only wrapper around the collection. Making the return type a read-only interface implemented by the collection and returning the actual collection reference doesn't provide much protection: the caller can easily cast to the "real" collection type and then add without any problems.

Comment: thanks Jon.  In my scenario, ObA is a DTO, I'm adding to one of its members through a service class... What would you suggest is the preferred approach, assuming I want to keep the DTO as behavior free as possible (meaning, I'd like to be basically a dummy data holder that has no business logic within).

Comment: umm... I meant I'd like *it to be ... I'm afraid personally I have no choice in the matter of being a dummy data holder :)

Comment: If it's *really* meant to be a "dumb" class, and all its clients will *know* that the collection may very well be modified by other callers, then it's okay to go with it as it is. I would document this very explicitly though - something like: "This property returns a direct reference to the backing collection: any changes made via this reference will be seen by other callers."

Comment: I think, generally you want an immutable collection. I men you get a list and it changes under you? But premature optimisation creeps in and you get a read-only copy of a transient form.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, not a good idea. Do not publish your mutable members outside, make a copy if you cannot provide a read-only version on the fly...

```
public class ObA{
  private List<String> foo;
  public List<String> getFoo(){return Collections.unmodifiableList(foo);}
  public void addString(String value) { foo.add(value); }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. Thanks!

Comment: I think it really depends - I would normally absolutely agree, but occasionally I find it *does* make sense to have truly dumb DTOs which don't really try to do much in the way of encapsulation.

Comment: Even in case of DTO, as much as possible. As Joshua Bloch( or Brian Goetz?) said, unless there is a really really good reason not to, make the object immutable.
Of course a special case is Java Bean object, which has setters and getters... but other than that ... try to make every object immutable or provide methods to perform mutability(you have to have total controll over that).

Comment: I think a good rule of thumb would be to never return backing data structures if you're exposing a 'public' API. If the method only has package access you're controlling when the method gets called and wrapping read-only collections is silly IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an opinion about doing this, I'd remove the `getFoo()` call and add an `add(String msg)` and `remove(String msg)` methods (or whatever other functionality you want to expose) to ObA

Comment: adrian beat you to the punch with this answer, but I'm giving you a vote up anyway, since you didn't know that was happening as you were typing :)

Comment: Of course you can add also ObA.remove(String value) or any other desired methods to manipulate foo...

Answer (score 1):

Giving access to collection always seems to be a bad thing in my experience--mostly because they are virtually impossible to control once they get out.  I've taken to the habit of NEVER allowing direct access to collections outside the class that contains them.

The main reasoning behind this is that there is almost always some sort of business logic attached to the collection of data--for instance, validation on addition or perhaps some day you'll need to add a second closely-related collection.

If you allow access like you are talking about, it will be very difficult in the future to make a modification like this.

Oh, also, I often find that I eventually have to store a little more data with the object I'm storing--so I create a new object (only known inside the "Container" that houses the collection) and I put the object inside that before putting it in the collection.

If you've kept your collection locked down, this is a trivial refactor.  Try to imagine how difficult it would be in some case you've worked on where you didn't keep the collection locked down...

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to support add and remove functions to Foo, I would suggest the methods addFoo() and removeFoo().  I ideally you could eliminate the getFoo at together by creating a method for each piece of functionality you need.  This make it clear as to the functions a caller will preform on the list.